# Permeable pavers for patio?

Tags: patio, stone, pavers

Currently we have a traditional deck off of the kitchen that needs the boards replaced. Rather than switching to composite decking, I was thinking of pulling the deck and putting in permeable pavers (Turfstone) with a much shortened deck stepdown (about 4' of deck as a step to the turfstone).

Has anyone used these in a patio setting (instead of a driveway setting)?
And, I live in Maine, meaning that I get snow that has to be shoveled. A deck is relatively smooth to remove snow from, but how is a permeable patio going to respond to being shoveled?

Comment: Frost heaving is a problem in Maine so a patio made with pavers has to have a very deep base. It will not be cheap to construct.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in Minnesota (-30F to +95F), and plenty of folks here have paver patios. I have one, and I'm currently building a Z-brick walkway around my garage (they're overkill, but I got a mountain of them for almost nothing). They do move sometimes, but they tend to settle back in after frost is out.

Permeable pavers are typically only used to skirt maximum non-permeable surface restrictions. Unless you have a very permeable base soil they don't do much for drainage. I'd go with less expensive conventional products.

Shoveling isn't really a problem due to the chamfered edges of most pavers. You'll catch the occasional rogue edge, but you do with any hard surface. Plastic shovels glide better than metal.